# How does "dare" change in indirect speech?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, indirect-speech, semi-modals

In indirect speech some modal verbs usually change.

**can -> could**

> He said "I can ride a bike" = He said that he could ride a bike

**may -> might/could**

> He asked "May I use the bathroom?" = He asked whether he could use the bathroom

But what about dare? It can be a modal verb.

> "No one dare go there" he whispered = He whispered ...

Comment: He whispered that no one dare to go there?

Comment: "He whispered that no one ***durst*** go there." Unfortunately, *durst* is around 150 years out of date. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whether+he+durst&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10). The modern wording would simply be *dare*, as @tac suggests.

Comment: The infinitive _dare_ by itself works: _He whispered that no one dare go there_.

Comment: *They wouldn't dare.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This *Collins Dictionary* grammar note](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/us/easy-learning/when-do-you-use-dare-and-need-in-english#:%7E:text=The%20past%20form%20needed%20is,are%20all%20negatives%20or%20questions.) says that both *dared* or *dare* can be the past tense of the modal *dare*:

> The past form needed is not used as a modal; dared is occasionally used as a modal.
> The modal uses of these verbs are all negatives or questions.

Thus, when you change "'No one dare go there' he whispered," to indirect speech, both

> He whispered that no one dare go there,
> He whispered that no one dared go there,

are valid forms.

You can also use the non-modal verb *dare*, in which case you get

> He whispered that no one dared to go there.

Comment: You don't refer to situations where you don't use backshifting because, for example, you think the situation is still true right? In other words, I can go on with the list: can->could, will->would, may->might/could, need->need, dare->dare/dared, ...

Comment: If the situation is still true, you don't need to backshift. But I didn't think that was what you were asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Just as *could* is the past tense of *can,* *dared* is the past tense of *dare,* regardless of whether it's used as an auxiliary. [This sentence quoted in the *Times* gives a good example:](https://www.nytimes.com/1974/09/01/archives/when-patti-wowed-her-fans-she-really-undid-them-the-one-thing-patti.html)

> He appealed to the sentinels of the greenroom; and these shook their heads, amidst roars of protest from the audience, and at last, with elaborate gestures, conveyed in dumb show that they **dared not, could not, would not, must not** venture to approach Patti again.

*Dared, could,* and *would* are all past tense. *Must* lacks a past tense, though, so it can't get backshifted with the others.

(My description of *could* and *would* as past-tense forms comes from Huddleston & Pullum (2002); other sources might disagree, but sentences like this illustrate the clear parallelism.)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149232/discussion-on-answer-by-alphabet-how-does-dare-change-in-indirect-speech); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.